# GruntJS assemble parsing Json file by helper to partial

Tags: json, gruntjs, handlebars.js, assemble

I want to parse json file via helper to partial. I am currently using technique from this site:

[Parsing Json data into partial](http://assemble.io/helpers/helpers-data.html)

It works very well but I would like to parse entire json file:

```
{{#parseJSON jsonfile}}
```

instead of doing this:

```
{{#parseJSON '{"id": "firstname", "label": "First name"}'}}
```

#each helper works by passing Json file

```
{{#each jsonfile}}
  {{> partial}}
{{/each}}
```

Is it possible to do this with custom helper?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a custom helper. You can either make a block helper that works like the `{{#each}}` helper or you can make an inline helper that will return the json object to iterate over and use it as a sub-expression.

**data.json**

```
{
  "brian": { "id": "brian", "label": "Brian" },
  "cataylyst": { "id": "cataylyst": "label": "The Cataylyst" }
}
```

**block helper**

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var each = Handlebars.helpers.each;
Handlebars.register('eachJSON', function(filepath, options) {
  try {
    var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(filepath), 'utf8'));
    return each.call(this, data, options);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return ''
  }
});
```

**inline helper**

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
Handlebars.register('readJSON', function(filepath, options) {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(filepath), 'utf8'));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return ''
  }
});
```

**usage**

```
{{!using the block helper}}
{{#eachJSON "data.json"}}
  {{> partial this}}
{{/each}}

{{!using the inline helper with the built in each block}}
{{#each (readJSON "data.json")}}
  {{> partial this}}
{{/each}}
```

I prefer the second approach because it gives you the option to use the `readJSON` helper in other places. Also, using the built in `each` helper ensures that you'll get the same functionality as using the `each` helper with an object or array that's already on the context.

Hope this helpers.